# GWT Propagate event through AbsolutePanel

Tags: events, gwt, celltable

I have a CellTable with ClickableCell. When I click on it, a popup opens and show the clicked cell table as exepected. The CellTable is added in a AbsolutePanel(Parent).

For some developpment, an another AbsolutePanel(Over) is located over the CellTable.

How can I propagate the AbsolutePanel(Over) click event on the celltable ?

I had an handler on the AbsolutePanelHandler(Over) and fired the clicked event :

```
absolutePanelOver.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            NativeEvent nativeEvent = Document.get().createClickEvent(0, -event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY(), 
                    event.getClientX(), event.getClientY(), event.isControlKeyDown(), event.isAltKeyDown(), 
                    event.isShiftKeyDown(), event.isMetaKeyDown());
            DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(nativeEvent, cellTable);
        }

    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Unfortunately the popup cell table is not shown. But I know that the cellTable handles the event.

Regards

Comment: Is control coming into onclick method after you click on absolute panel ??

Comment: @Baadshah After clicking on the absolute panel, the event is propagated to the celltable but not to the ClickableCell.

Comment: @Baadshah It's not necessary to delete your first answer. It prooves that my question was not totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand your question, but the solution seems to be much simpler.

```
absolutePanelOver.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        doSomething();
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

In your CellTable you invoke the same doSomething() method when a cell is clicked. Now it does not matter whether a cell or an absolute panel is clicked - the same method will be executed.